# How to append Text in xaml Textblock or rich textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm creating a chat app in Windows 8 Windows Metro Style App. I need to append the conversation in a `richtextblock` or `textblock` in XAML. Would somebody tell me the equivalent for this Code block?

```
public void AppendConversation(string str)
{
    conversation.Append(str);
    rtbConversation.Text = conversation.ToString();
    rtbConversation.Focus();
    rtbConversation.SelectionStart = rtbConversation.Text.Length - 1;
    rtbConversation.ScrollToCaret();
    rtbSendMessage.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since WPF uses `System.Windows.Controls` instead of `System.Windows.Forms`, we must consider the following**

1. `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` does not have a property for `Text` to set its value, we may set its value creating a new class of `TextRange` since the control depends on `TextPointer` which can be defined using `TextRange`

```
string _Text = ""
new TextRange(
  rtbConversation.Document.ContentStart,
  rtbConversation.Document.ContentEnd).Text = _Text;
```

---

2. Selections in `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` does not depend on `int` yet they  are held by `TextPointer`. So, we can't say

```
rtbConversation.SelectionStart = rtbConversation.Text.Length - 1;
```

but we can say

```
int TextLength = new TextRange(
  rtbConversation.Document.ContentStart,
  rtbConversation.Document.ContentEnd).Text.Length;
TextPointer tr = rtbConversation.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(
  TextLength - 1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
rtbConversation.Selection.Select(tr, tr);
```

which will do the same as `rtbConversation.SelectionStart = rtbConversation.Text.Length - 1;`

**Remark**: You can always retrieve the beginning of the selection in WPF using `RichTextBox.Selection.Start`

**Notice**: `RichTextBox.Selection.Start` outputs a class of name `TextPointer` but not a struct of name `int`

---

3. Finally, `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` does not have a definition for `ScrollToCaret();`. In this case, we may use one of the following voids regarding your control `rtbConversation`

```
rtbConversation.ScrollToEnd();
rtbConversation.ScrollToHome();
rtbConversation.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double offset);
rtbConversation.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double offset);
```

---

So, your void should look like this in WPF

**Example**

```
public void AppendConversation(string str)
{   
    conversation.Append(str) // Sorry, I was unable to detect the type of 'conversation'
    new TextRange(rtbConversation.Document.ContentStart,
                  rtbConversation.Document.ContentEnd).Text =
                    conversation.ToString();
    rtbConversation.Focus();
    int TextLength = new TextRange(rtbConversation.Document.ContentStart,
                                   rtbConversation.Document.ContentEnd).Text.Length;
    TextPointer tr = rtbConversation.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(
        TextLength - 1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    rtbConversation.Selection.Select(tr, tr);
    rtbConversation.ScrollToEnd();
    rtbSendMessage.Focus();
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @ggsmartboy No problems at all. I'm glad I could help. [Please notice that you may mark a post as an answer to indicate that you have already solved the problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks again. . . Make a nice day. . .